# Datatables datepicker/date range filter not working

Tags: filter, datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-range

I am trying to implement a date-range/datepicker filter on my table. My code doesn't work and I cannot understand why. The only breakpoint that gets hit when I debug is:

```
onSelect: function () {
        lTable.draw();
    },
```

No other breakpoints get hit. When I select a date, nothing happens. I've scoured the web for weeks trying to figure out the problem.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                        var from = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
                        var to = $('#to').datepicker("getDate");

                        //data being searched
                        var startDate = new Date(data[2]);

                        //if true show row/ if not, don't
                        if (from == null && to == null) { return true; }
                        if (from == null && startDate <= to) { return true; }
                        if (to == null && startDate >= from) { return true; }
                        if (startDate <= to && startDate >= from) { return true; }
                        return false;
                    }
                );    

                //DATE RANGE FILTER
                var lTable = $("WTM_LOG").DataTable();
                $("#to").datepicker({
                    onSelect: function () {
                        lTable.draw();
                    },
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                });

                $("#from").datepicker({
                    onSelect: function () {
                        lTable.draw();
                    },
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                });

                // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
                $('#from, #to').change(function () {
                    lTable.draw();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this block:

`onSelect: function() {
   lTable.draw();
 },`

And change your listener to this. Try putting it inside your `$(document).ready()`:

`$('#from, #to').on('keyup change', function () {
     lTable
         .order([2, 'asc']) // asc or desc
         .draw();
 });`

Comment: Thank you and sorry, only just saw this as I've been on holiday. I have tried the suggestion but it doesn't do anything.